# Countdown live timer in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, timer, countdowntimer

I'm trying to write a code prints the time in one line 
meaning, instead of printing it like this:

```
00:00:03

00:00:02

00:00:01
```

I want it to be printed in one line so after one second the next time will overwrite with the previous time until it reaches 1

I had this code so far

```
import time,sys

def countdown(t):
    while t:
        m, s= divmod(t,60)
        h, m = divmod(m,60)
        time_left=str(h).zfill(2)+":"+str(m).zfill(2)+":"+str(s).zfill(2)
        print(time_left, end='\r',flush=True)
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1
```

I tried all the solutions suggested online but all of them for python 2